# how to download xls file in python?

Tags: python, html, urllib

I am working on downloading a file from html page.
for example

```
html = 'www.abcd.com'
```

I parse the HTML page and find the links in that page.

Now I have the links from html page. But, the links are in following format :

```
i/ma/$File/ABCD.xls
```

but because of $File, I am not able to download the file.
  what is the way to download such files with such internal links?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create complete URL from hostname and relative path using `urlparse.urljoin()`.

Comment: i know that but I am asking about $File which comes in inner link. it dont allow to be right url. what can we do in that case?

Comment: @sam: How does the $File part stop you from downloading the link? Does urllib refuse to construct a URL with $ in it?

Comment: @paul : it dont refuse, but the downloaded .xls file is not same as original .xls. only one column filled

Comment: @sam: that’s very strange. Any idea how the problem resolved itself?